# Factorial iterative illegal argument - clojure

Tags: clojure

```
    (defn fac [n]
      (def result 1)
      (loop [i n c 1]
        (if (<= c 5)
          result
          (recur (* c i) (inc c))
          )
        )
      (println result)
      )

    (fac 5)
```

Error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: loop requires a vector for its binding.

I am trying to write a function that evaluates a numbers factorial. Where is my mistake? It gives me 1 as answer

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the code here as you actually ran it?  It works for me.  It prints `1`.

Comment: @NathanDavis i am trying to find 120

Comment: Ok, maybe I misread your question.  But how does the bit about `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  loop requires a vector for its binding` come into play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight:

- Don't use a `def` inside a `defn`.
- The REPL will print the result of evaluating a function. Use it.

This gets us to

```
(defn fac [n]
  (loop [i n c 1]
    (if (<= c 5)
      result
      (recur (* c i) (inc c)))))
```

... which doesn't compile, because `result` is floating.

There are a few corrections required:

- Return `i`, not `result`.
- Start `i` at `1`, not `n`.
- Turn the test around: `>` instead of `<=`.

We end up with

```
(defn fac [n]
  (loop [i 1, c 1]
    (if (> c n)
      i
      (recur (* c i) (inc c)))))
```

... which works:

```
(fac 5)
=> 120
```

---

Edited to correct one-off error and improve explanation.

Comment: Thanks but I can not print i out of the loop